# Hot swap render method from Slick2D

Tags: java, slick2d, hotswap

I'm trying to do code hot swapping in Eclipse using the Slick2D framework.
The problem is that I cannot do it inside `BasicGame#render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g)`, although I can do it in `BasicGame#update(GameContainer gc)`. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hot swapping code doesn't always work.  From the eclipse documentation:

> Note that some changes such as new or deleted methods, class
>   variables or inner classes cannot be hot swapped, depending on the
>   support provided by a particular VM.

Comment: Ok, so apparently there's an apparent 'locking' of some methods that a user may not be able to know of. Thank you ;)